# Why can 'lower' be a verb but 'higher/upper' cannot?

Tags: verbs, history, comparatives

The title is basically my question.
The word **lower** can be a comparative form of **low** as an adjective, but it can also be a verb.

However, the antonym of the word such as **higher** or **upper** cannot be used as a verb.

Why is this? Or is there any other antonym of **lower** that can function as a verb?

Comment: The antonym of the verb "lower" is the verb "raise" ... (I'm not sure from your question whether you know that already).

Comment: I mean I know "raise" might count as an antonym, but what I meant was, why is it not "upper" or "higher"? The direct antonym of "low" is "high". But then, lower can be a verb but higher cannot be? Isn't this strange?

Comment: While _upper_ may not be used as a verb, it's interesting how _up_ can be, as in: _He upped his game._

Comment: I've altered the tags here because this phenomenon is not restricted to AmE, and it seems the answer will be buried in the historical development of the language.

Comment: *Higher* has been used as a verb. See [Laurel's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/464431/210913). There is no reason that *upper* cannot be used as verb. It's just that it hasn't been. Feel free to start using it as such.

Answer (score 2):

You say it can't, but people *do* use it as a verb. It's not very common (often "raise" is used instead), but it's listed in the Oxford English Dictionary, which gives this example from the Birmingham Post (2012):

> Egress [is] made easier for the driver by the steering wheel being automatically highered when the engine is switched off and lowered again when it is started.

Furthermore, this verb usage is old, dating back to at least [1592](https://books.google.com/books?id=1Zw6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA553&lpg=PA553&dq=%22Yt+ys+alledged+that+the+bridge%22).

[Here](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&biw=1440&bih=732&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Csbd%3A1&tbm=bks&ei=EiudW-r6GIa0ggeE1IBw&q=%22he+highered%22&oq=%22he+highered%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...7437.7707.0.7983.3.3.0.0.0.0.76.218.3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.hm3GQsGrwU8) are some more examples.

It's usually used in contrast to "lower" (verb).

Comment: +1. I felt sure I'd heard it used colloquially in the sense of 'higher up the seat, will you?' I didn't find it in the dictionaries I checked in, but perhaps it's in the OED.

Comment: And *upper*? Are you saying, or implying, that it "can't" be used as a verb because it is not in the OED as such?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is speculative.

Perhaps it's a case of [blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(linguistics)), where the slot for *higher* as a verb was already occupied at the time that the verb *lower* entered the language by way of its older adjective.
 [Raise](https://www.etymonline.com/word/raise#etymonline_v_3312)  (in the sense of making higher from ca 1300) had already been in use for some 300 years when the verb [lower](https://www.etymonline.com/word/lower#etymonline_v_14564) entered the language in 1600 first as an intransitive verb and about 50 years later as a transitive verb.